# No super user for postgresql

Tags: linux, postgresql, ubuntu

Trying to run the following on postgresql:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS pg_trgm
```

but I get:

```
HINT:  Must be superuser to create this extension.
```

I was logged in as `postgres`

So I checked user roles:

```
 Role name |                   Attributes                    | Member of 
-----------+-------------------------------------------------+-----------
 devserver |                                                 | {}
 postgres  | Create role, Create DB, Replication, Bypass RLS | {}
```

What can I do here to add a super user? Reinstalling makes no difference. Just returns to this exact state.

`OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS x86_64`

Comment: your postgres user does not have superuser roles, quite weird. Are you using postgres profile user to do the query? If no, can you try `sudo -i -u postgres` on ubuntu -> `psql` and test the command again?

Comment: It logs into the user account but outputs: `To run a command as administrator (user "root"), use "sudo <command>".
See "man sudo_root" for details.`

Comment: then try `sudo -i -u postgres` -> `sudo psql`

Comment: Oh yea, that was another problem I had. There is no password set for postgres for some. I was never prompt for one when I installed either so I cannot use `sudo psql`

Comment: sudo psql, the password is your ubuntu password, the root account password. it means asking super user on ubuntu to do something for you, so it prompt the password to let's you enter super user password which should be your current account password.

Comment: it is normal, postgres user does not have password because in practice once installed, use it to create another superuser or user with specific role and never use postgres user (God user) again.

Comment: My superuser/root password does not work with it. I only use two passwords on this machine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232531/discussion-between-mic-fung-and-ben-owen). let's chat in the chatroom.

Answer (score 1):

If you have given away superuser status from all of your users, then you will need to shutdown the database and restart it in single-user mode to restore superuser to at least one user.

```
echo 'alter user postgres superuser' | postgres --single -D /path/to/db
```

"Reinstall" probably means you reinstalled just the software itself, but it is still using the same data files as it had before, which retains the same settings, which includes the deficit of superusers.  If the current database contains no info of value, you could just blow it away and recreate it.  One way to do this it specify `--purge` when uninstall with `apt`.

Comment: To uninstall it you need to specify individual packages. `sudo apt purge postgres` is not enough